# How to join two tables without duplicates?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an in table that looks like this:

```
id_in  | date_in   
-------|--------------------------
1      | 2016-04-29 02:00:00
```

And an out table that looks like this:

```
id_out    |  date_out
----------|--------------------------
1         | 2016-04-29 03:00:00
2         | 2016-04-29 04:00:00
3         | 2016-04-29 05:00:00
```

I want to write a query whose output looks like this:

```
id_in | date_in                     | id_out                     | date_out
------|---------------------------- |----------------------------|---------------------------
1     | 2016-04-29 02:00:00         | 1                          |2016-04-29 03:00:00
NULL  |  NULL                       | 2                          |2016-04-29 04:00:00
NULL  |  NULL                       | 3                          |2016-04-29 05:00:00
```

Comment: You're looking for `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN`

Comment: Why dont put it in one table instead of two? Seems unnecessary to split it up

Comment: Add another row to `in` table, with id = 4. And adjust the result, if needed.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this with a `left join`:

```
select i.id_in, i.date_in, o.id_out, o.date_out
from outtable o left join
     intable i
     on o.id_in = i.id_out;
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do this with a `right join`

```
select i.id_in, i.date_in, o.id_out, o.date_out
from intable i right join
     outtable o
     on o.id_in = i.id_out;
```

Comment: better avoid of using right join.. left join is better :)

Comment: @Yair.R No it's not, where did you get that information?  As a matter fact `table A LEFT JOIN table B` is **exactly** the same as `table B RIGHT JOIN table A`

Comment: @Daan . . . `LEFT JOIN` actually *is* better because of the way that SQL parses the `FROM` clause, from left-to-right.  For two tables, it doesn't make a difference, but when you chain the tables together, it is better for the join logic to follow the parsing logic.

Comment: Same result, but too confusing for most people. (They have problems enough with left join... I never encourage right joins.)

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the table with `id_in` 'table_in' and the table with `id_out` 'table_out'

You want to **join** table_in to table_out. In this case, you want to **left join** table_in to table_out on the `id` field. This will ensure you return **all** records from table_out regardless of whether they have a corresponding record in table_in:

```
select table_in.id_in, table_in.date_in, table_out.id_out, table_out.date_out
from table_out
left join table_in
on table_out.id_out = table_in.id_in
```

(Alternatively, you can `table_in right join table out` for the same results)

If you want **all** the records from **both tables** regardless of whether there is a corresponding record in the other, you should use `full join`.

Answer (score 0):

simple you can try this

```
select * from table_id i right join table_out o on i.id_in = o.id_out
```

Answer (score 0):

This query results the same as your need..

```
SELECT a.id_in, a.date_in, b.id_out, b.date_out
FROM intable AS a RIGHT JOIN
     outtable AS b
     ON a.id_in = b.id_out
```